# StatsModel logit.predict error: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and new values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, predict

I have a train dataframe(227845 lines) and a test dataframe (56962 lines).
What I want to do is to run a statsmodel logit regression on the train data and then predict the values for the test data. But after I train my model when I try to predict the test values I get the error :

```
PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and train.loc[:, train.columns != 'Class'] (56962 versus 227845)
train['Class'] ~ train.loc[:, train.columns != 'Class']
```

My steps for the analysis are:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataS =  pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
train, test = train_test_split(dataS , test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

Data Columns:

```
['Time' 'V1' 'V2' 'V3' 'V4' 'V5' 'V6' 'V7' 'V8' 'V9' 'V10' 'V11' 'V12'
 'V13' 'V14' 'V15' 'V16' 'V17' 'V18' 'V19' 'V20' 'V21' 'V22' 'V23' 'V24'
 'V25' 'V26' 'V27' 'V28' 'Amount' 'Class']
```

```
mod = logit("dataS['Class']  ~ dataS.loc[:, dataS.columns != 'Class']", data = dataS).fit()

predictions = mod.predict(test.loc[:, test.columns != 'Class'])
```

I tried to run it with `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` and with `statsmodel.Logit` and in both cases `predict()` was working fine but the statistics for the analysis where not the ones that I expected comparing it with the smf model.

Can someone help?

Comment: You should add tags so more people will see your question. `pandas` and `scikit-learn` I assume? Also, instead of the image of the error, paste the text itself. And add more code. Now it's impossible to know what is the problem with it.

Comment: @Georgy : I do not have the reputation required for more accurate tags. Thank you for your comment, I edited my question so as to be more detailed.

Comment: You are using the formula interface but don't specify a proper formula. Use DataFrames with the standard interface with Logit. In the standard array/DataFrame interface a constant is not added automatically and has to be added by the user.

Comment: @ user333700: thank you for your reply, I changed it to the classic Y ~ X1 + X2 and it worked.